# What is the relation between path's options in, out, relative, and looseness?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path, tikz-angles, relative

The following example,

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\tikzmarknode{FooUp}{foo} & foo\\
foo & foo\\
foo & foo\\
\tikzmarknode{FooDown}{foo} & foo\\[1em]
bar & \tikzmarknode{BarUp}{bar}\\
bar & bar\\
bar & bar\\
bar & \tikzmarknode{BarDown}{bar}\\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, very thin]
  \draw (FooUp.north west)
    -- (FooDown.south west)
    to[out=-90, in=90, looseness=1] (BarUp.north west)
    -- (BarDown.south west);
  \draw (FooUp.north east)
    -- (FooDown.south east)
    to[out=-90, in=90, relative, looseness=1] (BarUp.north east)
    -- (BarDown.south east);
  \draw (FooDown.south east)
    to[out=-90, in=90, relative, looseness=2] (BarUp.north east);
  \draw (FooDown.south east)
    to[out=-90, in=90, relative, looseness=0.5] (BarUp.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

generates this output
[image]

I know that using `out=-90, in=90, relative` the angles are relative to the horizontal line.

However, I don't understand what the angles generated for `out=-90, in=90, relative` are relative to. They all seem to be the same regardless of the `looseness`, so how can just the start and end points' coordinate determine the `in` and `out` angles?

Comment: @Teepeemm, I have no idea how that happened. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: They are *relative* to a straight line connecting source and target. In `\draw (0,0) to[out=90, in=90, relative] (1,1);` the directions will be 135° because the angle between (0, 0) and (1, 1) is 45°. The `looseness` factor (which there are two of: out and in) just changes the distance of the control points. (There are also distance factors.) The [manual explains](https://tikz.dev/library-edges#sec-74.3) all these keys.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, oh, I see, thanks! Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it. On the other hand, I wonder if it is possible for the `out` angle to be relative to the straight line connecting the source with the node before it (similarly for `in`). I guess it's not possible because path is defined piecewise?

Comment: Just to make it clear: Neither `in` nor `out` are relative to anything if the option `relative` is *not* used. `90` just means 90 degrees counterclockwise (where 0 degrees is equal to a line going eastwards). But this has nothing to do with the current path.

Comment: @JasperHabicht _where 0 degrees is equal to a line going eastwards_ means that `in` and `out` are relative to the line going eastward, not that they are not relative to anything.

Comment: @Enlico You can take ir like this, but I meant that they are not relative to the path you are currently drawing. You last comment suggested that you thought they are. Maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, let me rephrase. I've understood that, (1) without `relative`, `in`/`out` are relative to the eastward horizontal, and that (2) with `relative` they are relative to the straight line connecting source and target; I wonder if it is possible, somehow, to make them (3) relative to the straight line connecting that point and the previous point or, if that's logically impossible (because there might be no previous point), a named point.

Comment: A syntax I can think of is something along the lines of `\draw (FooDown.south east) to[out=-90, in=90, relative=from (FooUp.north east), looseness=0.5] (BarUp.north east);`, where `relative=from (FooUp.north east)` means that the line relative to which the angle is measured is that going from `(FooUp.north east)`--->`(FooDown.south east)` (instead of `(FooDown.south east)`--->`(BarUp.north east);`, which happens with just `relative`).

Comment: But I see that my suggestion is rather broken, as it would probably require 2 `relative` options... Well, I guess at least I've clarified what I'm thinking of.

Comment: @Enlico I guess for such more complicated paths, a curve drawn using `.. controls (x1,y2) and (x2,y2) ..` is better suited. I am unsure, but maybe the above could be done with a custom style.